# Script works from PC but not on server

Tags: python, email, smtp, smtp-auth

I wrote a small python script to automatically send emails every day at 10 am. The script works fine from my Laptop running Linux Mint 18. But when I deploy the script to my server (droplet taken from DigitalOcean) running Ubuntu 16.04.3 the script gives an STMP authentication error.

Allow less secure apps to sign in and other settings are enabled on my Gmail account.

Here's the script -

```
import schedule
import time
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

fromaddr = "yadullahabidi@gmail.com"
toaddr = "yadullahabidi@gmail.com"
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['To'] = toaddr
msg['Subject'] = "Attendance for Yadullah Abidi"

body = "Good morning Surender Ji. I reached office at 10:00 AM today."
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(fromaddr,"password")
text = msg.as_string()
def job():
    server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)

schedule.every().day.at("08:00").do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

All SMTP actions are blocked with DigitalOcean and you need to create a ticket with Support via the control panel and ask to un-block SMTP. This was implemented  to prevent SPAM.

Your other option is to use a third party mail service that allow port 2525 for mail like mandrill or mailgun if the resolution process is too long.

Reference : https://meta.discourse.org/t/digital-ocean-is-blocking-outgoing-mail/66740/24

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a look